# django many to many relationship can't query properly

Tags: django

I have two models using many2many relationship , but I can not make the correct query using one model to another.
My code :

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name='Com_Team')
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

But when I want to make a query like this:

```
com = Team.objects.get(id = 1).competition_set.all()
```

I'v been told that:

```
'Team' object has no attribute 'competition_set'
```

I just don't know what to do next...
Thanks very much~~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've told Django to call the attribute `Com_Team` instead (with `related_name='Com_Team'`):

```
Team.objects.get(id=1).Com_Team.all()
```